# Parsing dates with correct time zone in perl with core modules only

Tags: perl, datetime

I have to do several checks with dates I read from a database.
For instance, I have to compare them with a perl script's local time.
I also have to determine the calendar date of a parsed date.
In order to have readable code, I I would like to have identical time zone information in both generated (`localtime`) and parsed (`strptime`) time objects.

The solution should be 1-file only, so the task should be done with core perl modules only (version 5.10). So the `DateTime`module doesn't seem like an option.

The closest I have come is `Time::Piece`, but there seems to be no way to get a time object by parsing that is identical to one obtained by `Time::Piece::localtime()`.

```
use Time::Piece;
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub mystrptime1 {
    my $datestr = shift;
    my $tzoffset = sprintf '%+03d00', localtime->tzoffset->hours;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("$datestr $tzoffset", '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %z');
}

sub mystrptime2 {
    my $datestr = shift;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($datestr, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S');
    # it will be interpreted as GMT, so subtract the time zone offset :-(
    return $t - Time::Piece::localtime->tzoffset;
}

my $FORMAT = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S';

for my $strptime (\&mystrptime1, \&mystrptime2) {
    my $lt = Time::Piece::localtime();
    say "localtime is $lt, tz offset is ", $lt->tzoffset();

    my $str = $lt->strftime($FORMAT);
    say "str is $str";
    my $g = $strptime->( $str );

    say "parsed time is $g, tz offset is ", $g->tzoffset();

    say "time difference is: ", $lt-$g;
    say "hour difference is: ", $lt->hour - $g->hour;
}
```

What I want is both hour difference and time difference of zero, which seems to be impossible.

Comment: @mpapec: That's what I'm calling. The problem is `Time::Piece::strptime` always considers the time in GMT unless `%z` is given in the format.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make both solutions work by by calling `localtime` on the `strptime` result:

```
sub mystrptime1 {
    my $datestr = shift;
    my $tzoffset = sprintf '%+03d00', localtime->tzoffset->hours;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("$datestr $tzoffset", '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %z');
    return Time::Piece::localtime($t->epoch);
}

sub mystrptime2 {
    my $datestr = shift;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($datestr, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S');
    # it will be interpreted as GMT, so subtract the time zone offset :-(
    $t -= Time::Piece::localtime->tzoffset;
    return Time::Piece::localtime($t->epoch);
}
```